# Dual external monitors with 2 dual-mode DisplayPort ports

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, xrandr

I have an HP Elitebook laptop with a docking station. The docking station has two dual-mode DisplayPort ports, and I have a monitor hooked to both. In Windows, I can get both monitors working independently. But in Ubuntu, they always have mirrored displays and only one is detected.

My graphics card is listed as `Intel® Haswell Mobile`

[Here's the paste from `xrandr --verbose`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12692482)

[Here's my `monitors.xml`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12718371/) and [here my `sudo lshw`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14184055/)

Comment: Could you also post `monitors.xml`  to paste.ubuntu.com?

Comment: Oh, you should have dropped me a comment back in October...  Can you do a `sudo lshw` too and post that to http://paste.ubuntu.com as well (and the hardware config from Windows would be nice as well)  After that, *leave a comment @Fabby!*  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Here's the [output from sudo lshw](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14184055/)

Comment: Thank you!  Favour returned!  Question upvoted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your displays are identical, please:

1. Make a back-up of your current `monitors.xml`:

   ```
   cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~/.config/monitors.bak
   ```
2. Download the [following `monitors.xml`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14197376/) and overwrite yours.
3. Log off and log on again! (If that doesn't help: reboot)

Comment: Is this file under root or user account? Either way I don't have it on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop setup. What's the fix in this case?

Comment: This was a very specific answer to a very specific question and doesn't apply in your case.  Please [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

The "DP2 disconnected" message point to deeper problem..

1. and after a short search I have to say, that most probably it is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1104230

   If this is your case, you can monitor the issue and use daily kernel build after the issue is fixed and use solution #3 bellow until the issue is fixed.
2. Another reason could be, that monitor on DP2 is not sending correct EDID info. Try to diagnose this by swapping the monitors physically. After that it should say "DP1 disconnected".

   If this helps, **let us know**, and you can probably succeed with `xrandr --addmode` commands. but be ready to weird behaviour after you undock the computer, because things will not go automatically and you should always switch display off before you undock/unplug.
3. Another solution for you could be to simply use another output RGB, DVI or HDMI as the second monitor, depend on what is available on your docking station.

   Understand that this is not a solution you are serching for, but most probably will work even after the issue #1 is fixed.

There is some helpless discussion on Intel pages with an Intel staff on that issue, but without any conclusion: https://communities.intel.com/thread/51364?start=0&tstart=0